# Forcing a negative bottom margin on Flash

Tags: javascript, css, flash, scrollbar, margin

I have an .swf navigation carousel that is 650 pixels high, the bottom 200 pixels being reserved for the reflection of the carousel. The reflection is very subtle and is not considered important information, so we would like to remove vertical scrollbars when the window is high enough to fit the topmost 450 pixels, but not the reflection.

I tried to accomplish this by setting a `margin-bottom: -200px` to the flash `<object>` but this only made the container's height shrink 200 pixels, causing the background pattern to cut before the bottom of the page. The Flash itself is still taking up 650 pixels.

Is there some "proper" fix to this, other than hiding/showing the scrollbars actively using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using css:

```
#idOfElement {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

My apologies, I thought you were trying to remove scrollbars from the element. If you want to get them off of the window, just do `body {overflow: hidden}`

Parts of the element will only get cut off when you do `overflow: hidden` if the content of the element is larger than its container, so you may want to look into that.

Try this to hide the overflow when the window height reaches 450px:

```
window.onresize = function () {
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    if (height > 450) {
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    }
}
```

An issue you may have with this is that some browsers like to fire a lot of resize events during resizing, instead of one after, which could impact performance. Paul Irish wrote a short blog post about mitigating this at http://paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/ and I think that jQuery's .resize() function does this automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately hiding the overflow will result in the reflection part not being shown at all. We'd like to show it if we have the space but not require scrollbars just for it.

Comment: Is it cutting off the reflection even when the window is high enough to display it?